# LaTeX code for curly H used for Hausdorff dimension

Tags: code

Does anybody know the LaTeX Code for curly H used for Hausdorff dimension?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do you have a reference? Have you checked [“How to look up a symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14)?

Comment: Have you tried $\mathcal{H}$?

Answer (score 46):

Below are two different math fonts that may assist you in what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{H}\quad\mathfrak{H}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

See the [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) under `Math Alphabets`.

[image]

An alternative source for all TeX and LaTeX package information and general documentation is [texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net/). For example, to find the symbol list, on can search for `comprehensive` and you will get two formats: a4 and letterpaper. Here is a snapshot:

[image]

Comment: @rich Upvoting or accepting the answer can be form of thanking lol :-)

Comment: @azetina: _please_ don't quote `www.ctan.org` (it puts unreasonable load on an old machine with poor connectivity, soon to be withdrawn), please use CTAN's preferred `mirror.ctan.org` instead.

Comment: @wasteofspace Or simply google `The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List` right? :-)

Comment: or else `texdoc symbols`

Answer (score 5):

Try this one:

Use the free package [mathrsfs](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathrsfs?lang=en)

```
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
```

Use the following to get the desired symbol:

```
$\mathscr{H}$
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: This is already included in azetina’s response.

Comment: Ahh, you are correct. Look, here was the problem. I was also looking for answers to the same question, I read his response. However it was a lot of information for a simple job. Naturally that answer did not help much. So I went on and looked for all by myself. When I found out, I thought of posting it and I did. My intention was not to disrespect, but to help someone out in hurry.

Answer (score 2):

A better way of doing it using the [MTPro2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html). Using this package, you can easily create the Hilbert space symbol with `$\mathscr{H}$`. Here is the image of what it generates.

[image]